# Vue.js : image displayed using require() cannot update

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm displaying an image like that:

```
<img :src="imageUrlAlt(this.form.logo_image)">
```

I tried many ways to display image, and only require() works with data bind. 
My script:

```
data: () => ({
                form: {
                    logo_image: null // data will be mounted when load page
                }
            }),
methods: {
imageUrlAlt(type) {
                    try {
                        return require('../../../../../storage/app/public/'+ type)
                    } catch (e) {
                        return  require('../../../../../storage/app/public/images/organization/alt-image.png')
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I'm load the view and inspect, the image source is something like "/images/logo.jpeg?b0c864c0f180003c61d83266b55df0c6", and an image look exactly the same with my image will be created in public/images, so I understanding that this one has been displayed instead of the original.
However, when I'm create a function to upload image, after refresh page, the image displayed still the old, because image in public/images still not updated or delete. How to fix that? Thanks a lot. And sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: One thing is you don't need to use `this.` in the template.

Comment: Thanks I will fix it.